# Usage of REF datatype in Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to understand how the REf datatype works. I gather from the Oracle documentation that REF is some type of pointer to an object.
This is how I tried using REF:

```
SQL> create type roo as object (
  2   a number,
  3   b REF roo);
  4  /

Type created.

SQL> create table yoo ( a roo );

Table created.
```

How do I now insert values into the table yoo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the following example:
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NESTED_TABLE